# Não consigo atribuir um valor ao último elemento de um array

Tags: array, loop, lista-encadeada

struct Numero{
        ishort num;
        Numero *next;
    };

```
ishort array[3];
array[0] = grid1;
array[1] = grid2;
array[2] = grid3;
array[3] = grid4;

ishort i = 0;

Numero *n;
Numero *t;
Numero *h;

//lista circular
while(i <= 3)
{
    n = new Numero;
    n->num = array[i];

    if(i == 0)
    {t = n;
    h = n;}

    t->next = n; //linka com n
    t = t->next; //aponta pra n

    if(i == 3)
    {
        n->next = h;
        n = n->next;
    }

    i++;
}

i = 0;

while(i <= 3)
{
    cout << h->num << ", ";
    h = h->next;
    i++;
}
```

Simples, criei uma função que recebe 4 valores (ex: 3, 5, 7 e 8)e os atribui em um array de 4 elementos, para serem então armazenados numa lista circular. Durante o loop do armazenamento, quando array[i] chega na vez 3, ele receberia array[3].

Mas na hora do 2º loop da impressão, imprime 3, 5, 7 e 0. Sendo que fiz tudo correto. Já não sei mais o que eu faço, alguma ajuda? Obrigado!

Comment: `ishort array[3];` os índices desse array é: 0, 1 e 2. Desse forma, você não conseguira atribuir valor para o indíce `array[3]`.

Comment: obrigado, acabei me passando por um simples detalhe